# Issues with Laravel 5's Route::bind()

Tags: laravel, model-binding, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm having a little problem trying out Laravel 5.

I followed the whole tutorial in laracasts and tried to do everything the same exact way they do it there, only I changed the name of the model, table and controller.

At some point something with Route::bind() stopped working and because of that, now when I try to access a route with a Wild Card, the view will come up, but without the data.

This is my **routes.php**

```
Route::bind('singers', function($slug, $route){
return App\Singer::whereSlug($slug)->first();
});

Route::resource('singers', 'SingerController', [
                                            'names' => [
                                                    'index' => 'singers_index',
                                                    'show' => 'singers_show',
                                                    'edit' => 'singers_edit',
                                                    'update' => 'singers_update',
                                                    'create' => 'singers_create',
                                                    'store' => 'singers_store',
                                                    'destroy' => 'singers_destroy',
                                                        ],
                                                ]);
```

These are some snippets of my **SingerController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateSingerRequest;
use App\Singer;

class SingerController extends Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function __construct(Singer $singer){
        $this->singer = $singer;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $singers = $this->singer->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('singers.list',compact('singers'));
    }

    public function show(Singer $singer){
        return view('singers.show', compact('singer'));
    }

    public function edit(Singer $singer){
        return view('singers.edit', compact('singer'));
    }

    public function update(Singer $singer, Request $request){
        $singer->fill($request->input());
        $singer->save();
        return view('singers.show', compact('singer'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('singers.new');
    }

    public function store(Singer $singer, CreateSingerRequest $request){
        $singer->create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('singers_index');
    }

    public function destroy(Singer $singer){
        $singer->delete();
        return redirect()->route('singers_index');
    }
}
```

Now. The reason I try to bind the variable 'singers' in routes.php, is because they do it in the videos, and that way, the code in the Controller is shorter. And it WAS actually working. And then I just added the destroy function and it all stopped working.
As I said, I can see the views, the tags, and any other text in them, but not the data that I pass, except for the index function, since I actually do the Eloquent search in the function itself.

Now here's a snippet of my show.blade.php

```
<b>Full Name: </b> {{ $singer->name.' '.$singer->lastname }}
<br>
<b>Age: </b> {{ $singer->age }}
<br>
<b>Country: </b> {{ $singer->country }}
<br>
<br>
<p>
    <b>Bio: </b> {!! nl2br($singer->bio) !!}
</p>

{!! HTML::linkRoute('singers_edit', 'Update', [$singer->slug], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE', 'route'=>['singers_destroy', $singer->slug]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My index view works fine, and the other views are just forms, but any view that I'm passing variables to isn't working, whether I pass it by doing this:

```
return view('singers.show',compact('singer'));
```

or this:

```
return view('singers.show')->with('singer',$singer);
```

So to recap:

- index -> fine.
- show -> won't show any data.
- create -> actually works and the new record is saved.
- edit -> error comes up because the wildcard isn't sent to the
  controller.

**Edit**

Paths

- **index (GET)**: /singers
- **show (GET)**: /singers/{singers}
- **create (GET)**: /singers/create
- **store (POST)**: /singers
- **edit (GET)**: /singers/{singers}/edit
- **update (PATCH)**: /singers/{singers}
- **destroy (DELETE)**: /singers/{singers}

Keep in mind that the {singers} wildcard is actually $singer->slug in each case, but the Route::bind() function doesn't allow me to call it whatever I want.
And of course before the first slash comes myserver/myproject/public

Comment: What exactly url do you use for show and update?

Comment: show route -> localhost/project/public/singers/{singers}          and edit route -> localhost/project/public/singers/{singers}/edit

I will edit my post so you can see them better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested it.

`Singer` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Singer extends Model {

}
```

`SingerController` - exact code you provided (this file was placed of course in `app\Http\Controllers` path.

In `routes.php` :

```
Route::bind('singers', function($slug, $route){
   return App\Singer::whereSlug($slug)->first();
});

Route::resource('singers', 'App\Http\Controllers\SingerController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'singers_index',
        'show' => 'singers_show',
        'edit' => 'singers_edit',
        'update' => 'singers_update',
        'create' => 'singers_create',
        'store' => 'singers_store',
        'destroy' => 'singers_destroy',
    ],
]);
```

As you see I've added here full namespace path: `'App\Http\Controllers\SingerController'` and not only `SingerController`.

I'ce created simple `Singer` table, with fields just `id` and `slug` - just for test (so I have only those 2 columns) and added 2 records:

```
id slug
1  abc
2  def
```

Views I've created:

`list.blade.php`:

```
@foreach ($singers as $s)
{{ $s->slug }}<br />
@endforeach
```

`edit.blade.php` and `show.blade.php` (exact same code):

```
{{ $singer->slug }}
{{ $singer->id }}
```

Now when I run:

`http://testpro/singers` I get result:

```
def
abc
```

as expected.

When I run:

`http://testpro/singers/abc/edit`

I get:

```
abc 1
```

as expected.

And when I run:

`http://testpro/singers/def`

I get:

```
def 2
```

as expected.

Everything seems to work fine here. Make sure you are using it the way I showed and it should work without any problem

Comment: Well, in my case I edited the RouteServiceProvider so I don't need to add the namespace. I edited it back to how it was originally and tried your example and it didn't work for me (which makes no sense). Then Ichanged everything back to how it is in my original post and it all works again (which makes even less sense).

I seem to be having some problems with cache. so i keep having to run command php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan route:scan && php artisan route:cache in my console.

Comment: These commands may be messing with the way my application works, but the thing is that, sometimes something isn't working, and an error comes up with something about my routes, and whatever I change the error doesn't change so i  just run those commands after editing the routes.php file and i can actually see a difference.

Just a sec ago,when i edited my code back to the way it was in my opening post, it started working again, then i ran those commands just to see what happened and it stopped working again, and then idk what i did and the app reacted the way it should.

Comment: I guess there's just something about route caching that i still don't understand. Now, thank you for taking the time to help me Marcin.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curios to see know if when you edited it back did you actually edit it or use a copy of the original. I just did that same tutorial and was totally stumped by Jeffrey's Magic, but looking at the API specifically on model binding here

http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

the critical point is your "wild card" has to be triggered in the active route for the bind anonymous function to fire.

In my case, using the original nominclature I had a wildcard of {slug}, but earlier and later he changes it to {song}. Somehow, I had left mine at song, which had no effect when I was re-assigning the variable.

`$song = $this->song->whereSlug($slug)->first();`

However, once you do the router bind, it will never catch because you are using the slug as your wildcard.

`$router->get('songs/{slug}', 'SongsController@show');`

So when you bind that bad boy to

`Route::bind('song', function($slug) //The first literal "slug" MUST be a literal
    {                                   //in the route we are searching!!!
        return \App\Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
    });`
It fails, becasue my wildcard filter is never matched, however change that song to slug and magic!

`Route::bind('slug', function($slug) //The first literal "slug" MUST be a literal
    {                                   //in the route we are searching!!!
        return \App\Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
    });`

So, my guess is you had a type-O somewhere and corrected it in your edits. It's subtle, especially using so many literals, and with no code type hinting there. But thats ok. We can't all be Jeffrey Way. So if your bind fails, double check that first.

Good Luck.